# Buscar palabras con una terminación determinada

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

He estado buscando una función o una manera de imprimir las palabras que terminen con 'ing' en uno de mis programas. Hasta ahora no he encontrado una manera de imprimirlas, solo consigo imprimir mis casos base de 'ing'. Espero puedan ayudarme. Les dejo el código del autómata que realiza todo esto:

```
import turtle
import time

def main ():
    sel = input("Selecciona la opcion deseada:\n[1] Lectura de archivo\n[2] Ingreso manual\n[3] Grafo\n[4] Salir\n")

    if sel == 1:
        lecturaArchivo()
    elif sel == 2:
        manual()
    elif sel == 3:
        dibujo()
    else:
        print ("Saliendo...")

    def lecturaArchivo():
    i = 0
    estado = 0
    caracteres = []
    ap = id(caracteres)
    archivo = open("Archivo.txt")
    salida = open("SalidaIng.txt","w+")

    caracteres = archivo.read()

    for ap in caracteres:
        if ap == 'i' and estado == 0:
            salida.write("Estado:")
            salida.write(str(estado))
            salida.write("\nLetra:")
            salida.write(str(ap))
            salida.write("\n\n")
            impresion(ap,estado)
            estado = 1
        elif ap == 'n' and estado == 1:
            salida.write("Estado:")
            salida.write(str(estado))
            salida.write("\nLetra:")
            salida.write(str(ap))
            salida.write("\n\n")
            impresion(ap,estado)
            estado = 2
        elif ap == 'g' and estado == 2 and caracteres[i+1] == ' ':
            salida.write("Estado:")
            salida.write(str(estado))
            salida.write("\nLetra:")
            salida.write(str(ap))
            salida.write("\n\n")
            impresion(ap,estado)

        elif ap == 'g' and estado == 2 and caracteres[i+1] !=' ':
            salida.write("Estado:")
            salida.write(str(estado))
            salida.write("\nLetra:")
            salida.write(str(ap))
            salida.write("\n\n")
            impresion(ap,estado)
            estado = 0

        elif ap == ' ':
            salida.write("Estado:")
            salida.write(str(estado))
            salida.write("\nLetra:")
            salida.write(str(ap))
            salida.write("\n\n")
            impresion(ap, estado)
            estado = 0
        else:
                salida.write("Estado:")
                salida.write(str(estado))
                salida.write("\nLetra:")
                salida.write(str(ap))
                salida.write("\n\n")
                impresion(ap,estado)
                estado = 0
    ap = id(caracteres[i+1])
    archivo = open("Archivo.txt","r")
    palabra = "ing"
    repetidas = 0 
    lines = archivo.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        palabras = line.split(' ')
        for p in palabras:
            if p==palabra:
                print line.find(palabra)
    pregunta()


def manual():
    texto = []
    palabras=[]
    posiciones=[]
    i = 0;
    ap = id(texto)
    id(palabras)
    estado = 0
    pos = 0
    salida = open("SalidaIng.txt","w+")
    texto = raw_input("Ingresa la cadena de texto en la que se buscara la 
    terminacion ing:")

    for ap in texto:
        if ap == 'i' and estado == 0:
            salida.write("Estado:")
            salida.write(str(estado))
            salida.write("\nLetra:")
            salida.write(str(ap))
            salida.write("\n\n")
            impresion(ap,estado)
            estado = 1
        elif ap == 'n' and estado == 1:
            salida.write("Estado:")
            salida.write(str(estado))
            salida.write("\nLetra:")
            salida.write(str(ap))
            salida.write("\n\n")
            impresion(ap,estado)
            estado = 2
        elif ap == 'g' and estado == 2 and texto[i+1] == ' ':
            salida.write("Estado:")
            salida.write(str(estado))
            salida.write("\nLetra:")
            salida.write(str(ap))
            salida.write("\n\n")
            impresion(ap,estado)

        elif ap == 'g' and estado == 2 and texto[i+1] !=' ':
            salida.write("Estado:")
            salida.write(str(estado))
            salida.write("\nLetra:")
            salida.write(str(ap))
            salida.write("\n\n")
            impresion(ap,estado)
            estado = 0

        elif ap == ' ':
            salida.write("Estado:")
            salida.write(str(estado))
            salida.write("\nLetra:")
            salida.write(str(ap))
            salida.write("\n\n")
            impresion(ap, estado)
            estado = 0
        else:
            salida.write("Estado:")
            salida.write(str(estado))
            salida.write("\nLetra:")
            salida.write(str(ap))
            salida.write("\n\n")
            impresion(ap,estado)
            estado = 0
    ap = id(texto[i+1])

    pregunta()

def dibujo():

    print "Una vez que termine de ver el grafo, presione enter en la terminal para salir."

    turtle.showturtle()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-250,0)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(30)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-260,25)
    turtle.write("q0",font=("Arial",20,"normal"))
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-220,30)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(135)
    turtle.dot(8)
    turtle.penup()

    turtle.goto(-50,0)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(30)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-60,25)
    turtle.write("q1",font=("Arial",20,"normal"))
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-20,30)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(140)
    turtle.dot(8)
    turtle.penup()

    turtle.goto(150,0)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(30)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(150,5)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(25)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(140,25)
    turtle.write("q2",font=("Arial",20,"normal"))
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(150,60)
    turtle.right(270)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(60,90)
    turtle.goto(-190,120)
    turtle.circle(60,90)
    turtle.dot(8)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-250,0)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.dot(8)
    turtle.circle(60,90)
    turtle.goto(-110,-60)
    turtle.circle(60,90)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-100,125)
    turtle.write("Diferente de ' ' o de final de cadena",font=("Arial",12,"normal"))
    turtle.goto(-180,-75)
    turtle.write("Diferente de g",font=("Arial",12,"normal"))
    turtle.goto(-160,35)
    turtle.write("n",font=("Arial",12,"normal"))
    turtle.goto(65,35)
    turtle.write("g",font=("Arial",12,"normal"))
    turtle.goto(-390,30)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(-280,30)
    turtle.dot(7)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-420,30)
    turtle.write("Inicio",font=("Arial",12,"normal"))
    turtle.goto(-370,35)
    turtle.write("Diferente i o i",font=("Arial",12,"normal"))
    raw_input()
    pregunta()

def pregunta():
    opcion = raw_input("Desea regresar al menu\n[1] Si\n[2] No\n")
    if opcion == '2':
        print "Saliendo..."
    else:
        main()


def impresion(ap,estado):
    print "Estado:",estado,"\nLetra:"+ap,"\n"

main()
```

Comment: Hola Alvarez, deberias identar correctamente tu codigo, en Python es esencial para interpretar el programa y saber el ambito de cada bloque de codigo. Por otro lado, las etiquetas referidas a "python 2" y "python 3" son mutuamente excluyentes. Parece que usas Pyhon 2, deja solo estas y la general de "python", la etiquta "buscador" tampoco se aplica en este caso..¿Cual es la idea de `ap = id(caracteres[i+1])`? ¿Porqué no incrementas simplemente `i` después de cada iteración del `for`o usas `enumerate`? Intentar modificar un iterable mientras se itera con un `for in` no es buena idea...

Comment: Creo que no se copió con las sangrías correspondientes. Estaba usando 'ap = id(caracteres[i+1]', como la dirección de memoria de la lista, después me di cuenta de que era innecesario, pero como funcionaba lo dejé jajaja. Pero tengo el problema que no se como imprimir las palabras que tengan ing, espero puedas ayudarme @FJSevilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que muestras ya hace más o menos lo que quieres, lo que necesitas básicamente esque cuando se detecte un estado 2 con un espacio se pueda retornar la palabra terminada en ing anterior. Para ello debes guardar el índice de la letra inicial de cada palabra.

Por otro lado, deberías refactorizar código. Tienes dos funciones con la mayoría de código idéntico. Saca el algoritmo común y lo pones en otra función.

Hay que considerar que una palabra es una subcadena separada por espacio pero también podría estar separada por saltos de línea o tabulaciones por ejemplo. Esto debes tenerlo en cuenta.

Por último no olvides nunca cerrar los archivos abiertos con `open` o usa la sentencia `with` para que sean cerrados de forma automática.

Tu código podría ser algo así (solo se muestran las funciones modificadas):

```
def lecturaArchivo():
    with open("Archivo.txt",  "rU") as archivo:
        caracteres = archivo.read()
    palabras = buscar(caracteres)
    print("Lista de palabras:",  palabras)     
    pregunta()

def manual():
    texto = raw_input("Ingresa la cadena de texto en la que se buscara la terminacion ing:")
    palabras = buscar(texto)
    print("Lista de palabras:",  palabras)
    pregunta()

def buscar(texto):
    estado = 0
    inicio = 0
    palabras = [] # Lista para almacenar las palabras encontradas

    with open("SalidaIng.txt", "w+") as salida:
        for i, ap in enumerate(texto):
            if ap == 'i' and estado == 0:
                salida.write("Estado: {}\nLetra: {}\n\n".format(estado,  ap))
                impresion(ap,estado)
                estado = 1
            elif ap == 'n' and estado == 1:
                salida.write("Estado: {}\nLetra: {}\n\n".format(estado,  ap))
                impresion(ap,estado)
                estado = 2
            elif ap == 'g' and estado == 2:
                salida.write("Estado: {}\nLetra: {}\n\n".format(estado,  ap))
                impresion(ap,estado)
            elif ap == ' ' or ap == '\n' or ap == '\t':
                if estado == 2:
                    palabra = texto[inicio:i] # Obtenemos la palabra
                    palabras.append(palabra)
                    print("Palabra encontrada: {}.".format(palabra))
                salida.write("Estado: {}\nLetra: {}\n\n".format(estado,  ap))
                impresion(ap,estado)
                estado = 0
                inicio = i+1 # Indice de primera letra de proxima palabra
            else:
                salida.write("Estado: {}\nLetra: {}\n\n".format(estado,  ap))
                impresion(ap,estado)
                estado = 0

        if estado == 2: # Por si la ultima palabra del archivo termina en ing
            palabra = texto[inicio:i+1]
            palabras.append(palabra)
            print("Palabra encontrada: {}.".format(palabra))
            salida.write("Estado: {}\nFin de archivo\n\n".format(estado))
            impresion(ap,estado)
        return palabras # Retornamos la lista con lo encontrado
```

Para un fichero ejemplo con el contenido:

> ```
> file waiting ingraft
>   sling the who  string
> ```

La salida es:

```
Selecciona la opcion deseada:
[1] Lectura de archivo
[2] Ingreso manual
[3] Grafo
[4] Salir
1

Estado: 0 
Letra:f 

Estado: 0 
Letra:i 

Estado: 1 
Letra:l 

Estado: 0 
Letra:e 

Estado: 0 
Letra:  

Estado: 0 
Letra:w 

Estado: 0 
Letra:a 

Estado: 0 
Letra:i 

Estado: 1 
Letra:t 

Estado: 0 
Letra:i 

Estado: 1 
Letra:n 

Estado: 2 
Letra:g 

Palabra encontrada: waiting.
Estado: 2 
Letra:  

Estado: 0 
Letra:i 

Estado: 1 
Letra:n 

Estado: 2 
Letra:g 

Estado: 2 
Letra:r 

Estado: 0 
Letra:a 

Estado: 0 
Letra:f 

Estado: 0 
Letra:t 

Estado: 0 
Letra:


Estado: 0 
Letra:  

Estado: 0 
Letra:s 

Estado: 0 
Letra:l 

Estado: 0 
Letra:i 

Estado: 1 
Letra:n 

Estado: 2 
Letra:g 

Palabra encontrada: sling.
Estado: 2 
Letra:  

Estado: 0 
Letra:t 

Estado: 0 
Letra:h 

Estado: 0 
Letra:e 

Estado: 0 
Letra:  

Estado: 0 
Letra:w 

Estado: 0 
Letra:h 

Estado: 0 
Letra:o 

Estado: 0 
Letra:  

Estado: 0 
Letra:  

Estado: 0 
Letra:s 

Estado: 0 
Letra:t 

Estado: 0 
Letra:r 

Estado: 0 
Letra:i 

Estado: 1 
Letra:n 

Estado: 2 
Letra:g 

Palabra encontrada: string.
Estado: 2 
Letra:g 

('Lista de palabras:', ['waiting', 'sling', 'string'])
Desea regresar al menu
[1] Si
[2] No
```

Dicho esto hay formas mucho mas simples y concisas de hacer esto en Python. Una de las mas flexibles es usar expresiones regulares, que te permiten obtener incluso los indices entre los que esta contenida cada palabra encontrada:

```
import re

def lecturaArchivo():
    with open("Archivo.txt",  "rU") as archivo:
        caracteres = archivo.read()
    print repr(caracteres)
    palabras = buscar(caracteres)
    print "Lista de palabras:",  palabras     

def buscar(texto):
    return [(m.group(),  m.start(0), m.end(0))
               for m in re.finditer(r'\b(\w+ing)\b', texto)]

lecturaArchivo()
```

**Salida**:

```
Lista de palabras: [('waiting', 5, 12), ('sling', 22, 27), ('string', 37, 43)]
```

Retorna una lista con tuplas en las que el primer elemento es la palabra, el segundo el indice de la primera letra y el tercero el de la última letra de esta en el texto original.